# Excel: Get the cell address of the first occurrence of a value and use it in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, lookup

I have the following table:

```
     A    B    C
 1   1    4    =(Formula) 
 2   1    
 3   3
 4   4
 5   4
```

I need to get the address of the first occurrence of the value in B1 (4 in this case) from column A (which is A4) and use that address in a formula (located say in C1). The formula should basically do the following:

1. If B1 is not empty, get the first occurrence of the value in B1 (in this example 4) in range A1:A10000 (in this case A4)
2. Use this address (A4) in a formula, to make a range of 20 cells: this_address:this_address+20 (In this example: A4:A24).
3. Do some calculations

All three steps should be performed in one single formula.

Comment: A4:A24 is 21 cells, not 20.

Comment: `=OFFSET(A1, MATCH(B1, A1:A1000, 0)-1, 0, 20, 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH and INDEX/MATCH+20:

```
INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B1,A:A,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B1,A:A,0)+20)
```

So if we wanted to sum that range:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B1,A:A,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B1,A:A,0)+20))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if I need to ask this as a separate question. But I'm curious if there is also a way that I get the row number of the first occurrence and append that to a column? In my example, let's say get 4 from A4, and make a range of D4:D24

Comment: yes it is another question, but before you ask look into the INDEX function.  It allows for two dimensional references.  There is a third optional criterion.  Also the OFFSET can do it with the third criterion.

Comment: Thanks. Will play with it. If couldn't figure it out, will ask another question! :-) Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 3):

While INDEX is the better choice, OFFSET should at least be mentioned.

```
'A4:A24
=offset(a1, match(b1, a:a, 0)-1, 0, 21, 1)
=sum(offset(a1, match(b1, a:a, 0)-1, 0, 21, 1))

'D4:D24
=offset(a1, match(b1, a:a, 0)-1, 3, 21, 1)
=sum(offset(a1, match(b1, a:a, 0)-1, 3, 21, 1))
```